# Navigation of matrix from left top to right bottom, only moving to the right or downwards?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

actual problem is like this which I got from an Online competition. I solved it but my solution, which is in C, couldn't produce answer in time for large numbers. I need to solve it in C.

Given below is a word from the English dictionary arranged as a matrix:

```
MATHE
ATHEM
THEMA
HEMAT
EMATI
MATIC
ATICS
```

Tracing the matrix is starting from the top left position and at each step move either RIGHT or DOWN, to reach the bottom right of the matrix. It is assured that any such tracing generates the same word. How many such tracings can be possible for a given word of length m+n-1 written as a matrix of size m * n?

1 ≤ m,n ≤ 10^6

I have to print the number of ways S the word can be traced as explained in the problem statement. If the number is larger than 10^9+7, I have to print S mod (10^9 + 7).

In the testcases, m and n can be very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine traversing the matrix, whatever path you choose you need to take exatcly n+m-2 steps to make the word, among of which n-1 are down and m-1 are to the right, their order may change but the numbers n-1 and m-1 remain same. So the problem got reduced to only select n-1 positions out of n+m-2, so the answer is

> C(n+m-2,n-1)=C(n+m-2,m-1)

**How to calculate C(n,r) for this problem:**

You must be knowing how to multiply two numbers in modular arithmetics, i.e.

`(a*b)%mod=(a%mod*b%mod)%mod`,

now to calculate C(n,r) you also need to divide, but division in modular arithmetic can be performed by using modular multiplicative inverse of the number i.e.

`((a)*(a^-1))%mod=1`

Ofcourse a^-1 in modular arithmetic need not equal to 1/a, and can be computed using Extended Euclidean Algorithm, as in your case mod is a prime number therefore

`(a^(-1))=a^(mod-2)%mod`

a^(mod-2) can be computed efficiently using repetitive squaring method.

Comment: I know this solution ,But how can I calculate the factoiral of large numbers such as 50 or 100 in problem it is mentioned that it can be upto 10^6.

Comment: can you please explain how (a^(-1))=a^(mod-2)%mod .

Comment: @vj1207 it's a property in modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a dynamic programming approach for this problem since calculation of factorials of large numbers shall involve a lot of time, especially since you have multiple queries.

Starting from a small matrix (say `2x1`), keep finding solutions for bigger matrices. Note that this solution works since in finding the solution for bigger matrix, you can use the value calculated for smaller matrices and speed up your calculation.

The complexity of the above soltion IMO is polynomial in `M` and `N` for an `MxN` matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laplace's triangle, incorrectly named also "binomial"

```
1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0

1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0

1  1  1  0  0
1  2  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0

1  1  1  1  0
1  2  3  0  0
1  3  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0

1  1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4  0
1  3  6  0  0
1  4  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0

1  1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4  5
1  3  6 10  0
1  4 10  0  0
1  5  0  0  0

1  1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4  5
1  3  6 10 15
1  4 10 20  0
1  5 15  0  0

1  1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4  5
1  3  6 10 15
1  4 10 20 35
1  5 15 35  0

1  1  1  1  1
1  2  3  4  5
1  3  6 10 15
1  4 10 20 35
1  5 15 35 70
```

Got it? Notice, that elements could be counted as binomial members. The diag members are here: C^1_2, C^2_4,C^3_6,C^4_8, and so on. Choose which you need.

Comment: I know it is like Pascal triangle but row and column in above problem may not be always same .